# Uppy to tus.io file checksums in Node.js

Tags: file-upload, crc32, uppy, tus

I’ve noticed [here](https://github.com/tus/tus-node-server/tree/main#extensions) that the checksum extension is not supported for the tus-node-server.

Is there any other recommended way I might be able to get (or calculate) the checksum in the onUploadCreate callback, or anywhere else?

For reference, I’m using the uppy dashboard with tus connected to the S3Store plugin.

Thanks